# Unable to append the date to the file name using log4j DailyRollingFileAppender

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, log4j

Hi I am trying to append the current date to the file name using log4j DailyRollingFileAppender, but its not working. I have used the configuration like below. Please suggest a solution for this

## properties

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, rollingAppender
log4j.appender.rollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.rollingAppender.File=F:/temp/app.log
log4j.appender.rollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n
```

I am expecting the log file as app2014-11-07.log, but its still app.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using log4j 1.x, we strongly recommend that you use [**`org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender`**](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html) <sup>**1**</sup> instead of [`org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html) (may lose messages, [Bug 43374](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43374)).

So the configuration of you appender can be:

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, rollingAppender
log4j.appender.rollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingAppender.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.rollingAppender.rollingPolicy.fileNamePattern=F:/temp/app%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
log4j.appender.rollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n
```

---

*Notes*

1. In that case, you need to add the respective jar ([apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=log4j/apache-log4j-extras/1.2.17/apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar)).

Comment: Tried this, its giving below error.log4j:WARN Failed to set property [rollingPolicy] to value "org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy".

log4j:WARN Please set a rolling policy for the RollingFileAppender named 'rollingAppender'

Comment: it's the same for me as for V Joe.

Comment: fyi, the bug case mentioned in this answer is closed as resolved.

Answer (score 2):

**DailyRollingFileAppender** means archiving log files.
For example, today is 2014.11.07, when you first run your app, your log file name would be `app.log`. Tomorrow, you run the app again,it's log file also named `app.log`, **but** yesterday's log file has been changed , maybe like `app.log.2014.11.07`

Try this :

1. Change your System Date, to be 2014.11.08
2. Run your app, then check out the log-path:`F:/temp/`

---

**OR**

Change this

```
    log4j.appender.rollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
```

to

```
    log4j.appender.rollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm
```

That means it will produce a new log file  minute-by-minute.
Run it again.

Comment: Is there any other way so that I will get even today's file with current date

Answer (score 0):

You can use this configuration:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
#log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%d](%F:%L) - %m%n
#log4j.appender.stdout.File=/usr/tomcat7/webapps/ngp/newgen.log
log4j.appender.stdout.File=c:/logs/DSP.log
#log4j.appender.stdout.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.stdout.append=false
```