# Configure log4j log file name if it is rolling?

Tags: java, log4j

log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=PATH_TO_LOGS/logs/rolling.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm
log4j.appender.file.threshold=debug
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p] %d %c - %m%n
log4j.rootLogger=debug,file
```

My log file is rolling every minute. 
But my problem is I want the rolled log file name to be:
`rolling.2016-03-17-11-11.log`

instead of

```
rolling.log.2016-03-17-11-11
```

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802822/unable-to-append-the-date-to-the-file-name-using-log4j-dailyrollingfileappender)

Comment: Have you added `apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
log4j.appender.file.File=PATH_TO_LOGS/logs/rolling.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm
```

Changed to:

```
log4j.appender.file.File=PATH_TO_LOGS/logs/rolling
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm'.log'
```